# jsonkit decoding

Tags: iphone, json

hi im using jsonkit to deserialize json kit data. this is the code i use.

```
NSString * strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data   
             encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

nslog(@"strresult");

NSDictionary *deserializedData = [strResult objectFromJSONString]; 

nslog(@"result");

o/p:
"data": {
  "translations": [
   {
    "translatedText": "hello"
   }
  ]
 }
}

 result {
    data =     {
        translations =         (
                        {
                translatedText = "\U091c\U093e\U0928\U093e";
            }
        );
    };
}
```

what is the problem????? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try to use http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/.

Your code will look like this. And you need to include `#import "JSON.h"`

```
NSString * strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"strresult");

NSDictionary *deserializedData = [strResult JSONValue];
```

I think the problem is from string encoding.